# SetPublishState from Page find PublishTransaction

Tags: web8.5, event-system

If you subscribe to the SetPublishState event for a Page is there any way to find the Publish Transaction it was part of?

The API exposes who published/unpublihsed, TargetType and ProcessedItems but not the Publish Transaction which seems odd.